# Jasmine unit testing - mat-Autocomplete filter class

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jasmine, observable

I'm writing jasmine unit tests for an angular app, coverage is pretty good, but struggling to find a good way to test observable filter classes for mat-autocomplete data population.

The ts class:

```
  dataFilter(val: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.getAPI.get()
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.filter(option => {
          return option.foo.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
        }))
      );
   }
```

unit test for this class so far:

```
  it('should test filtered data for autocomplete', () => {
    getApiSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(DATA));
    component.dataFilter("");
    expect(getApiSpy.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

This covers the first return (return this.getAPI.get()) but everything from the .pipe down is not covered. Has anyone tested these type of classes before and has any tips, what is the right approach?

Thanks,
Ollie

Comment: Your component.dataFilter(""); call sounds fishy here - you're getting a cold observable, with unexpected results.
component.dataFilter("").subscribe(() => { // tests here}) would be a better option.
Using a $ suffix for functions that return observables would help making these issues more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should filter', () => {

    const getApiMock = [
        { foo:'abc'},
        { foo:'def'},
        { foo:'xyz'},
    ];

    // spy on getAPI.get() and return getApiMock here...

    const expected = [
        { foo:'xyz'},
    ];

    component.dataFilter('Y').subscribe(actual => {
        expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! the dreaded pink line is gone from my code coverage report.

Comment: @YorkshireDevOliver Great! Please consider marking the response as accepted.